# Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$ have order $k$. If $x^p=a$, then $x$ has order $pk$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem Statement**

Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$ have order $k$. If $p$ is a prime divisor of $k$ and $x^p=a$, then $x$ has order $pk$.

**Question**

I don't really see why $p$ being a prime divisor matters. **I want to know what could go wrong if $p$ is not a prime divisor**

For example, if $a$ has order $18$ and $x^6=a$ then, since $18$ is the smallest positive integer for which $a^{18}=1$ we must have $(x^{6})^{18}=1$ so $6*18$ is the smallest number for which it happens. If we chose $m<18$, then we would have $(x^6)^{m}=a^m\neq 1.$ So, again, I don't see what goes wrong if $p$ is not prime.

Comment: I think it's OK provided that every prime divisor of $p$ divides $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am reading this wrong, there are lots of trivial counterexamples if you get rid of the prime condition. Take an easy group, like $Z_4$ and let $y$ be a generator, so of order 4. Then let $a=x=y$. In this case, $y^5=y$, clearly, but then the theorem fails: we have $p=5$, $k=4$, but the order of $y$ is 4, not $4*5=20$.

Comment: What if $p$ is a (nonprime) divisor of $k$? Is there a counter example for that case?